# How to make a fullscreen toggle button in the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I am making an options menu in the BGE and I want to know how to make a button that toggles fullscreen on and off for the blender game?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just have the cam move into a closer position that would make it appear that the menu was fullscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply done with a small python script using the [bge.render.setFullScreen()](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.render.html#bge.render.setFullScreen) function.

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

if cont.sensors['MouseOver'].hitObject.name == 'Cube' and cont.sensors['Lclick'].getButtonStatus(bge.events.LEFTMOUSE) == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
    if bge.render.getFullScreen() == True:
        bge.render.setFullScreen(False)
    else:
        bge.render.setFullScreen(True)
```

You then add the script to your button with these logic bricks.
[image: logic bricks]

The *MouseOver* and *Lclick* mouse sensors are used to start the script when the button is clicked.
Look through the [Blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2427/) for a full working example.
(*Note* you will need to start the **Standalone player** for full screen to work.)

Comment: Thank you this worked i just needed to rename some of my stuff to make it work i had a plane named Fullscreen so i changed the part of the script that said cube to Fullscreen and as for my sensers i just renamed them to what you already had in the script which was Lclick and MouseOver

Answer (score 2):

In order to do exactly that and not quickly toggle back to windowed, with a keyboard sensor named `keyboard`:

```
from bge import render
def fullScreenMode(cont):
    if cont.sensors["keyboard"].getKeyStatus(events.F11KEY) == logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE:
        if render.getFullScreen() == False:
            render.setFullScreen(True)
        else:
            render.setFullScreen(False)
```